# unable to install or run the application

Tags: c#, windows, ms-access

System Update Required:

[image]

Cannot open database connection :

[image]

Wrong username and password :

[image]

Greetings everyone
I have the following issue with restaurant management system that is programmed in C# connected with Microsoft Access database (2019), the program is work correctly in main developer laptop while we transfer the files to target or other PC or Laptop the program show the above images as windows messages error hopefully anyone have solved the issue before or have suggestion to solve it. let know about it with appreciation and advanced in thanks.
note* even I look for the problem I try to install new framework or Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Download the required version of log4net dll to the system. And then open Visual studio command prompt. Then run the below command in it.

```
gacutil -i log4net.dll
```

You need to install the dll in the GAC.

If by any change there is no gacutil or Visual Studio installed then you can use powershell to install the dll into GAC. You can refer this link for that https://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/powershell-install-gac-gacutil-for-powershell